# JQL Query To Show One Issue From Each User On The Board

Tags: jira, agile, jql

I've tried looking on the JIRA website and through the JQL Documentation. We've got a Kanban board that we're using, and ideally, I'd like it to show the highest priority issue per user that has an issue in the column before sorting in any other way.

Right now, I've got it ordered by priority DESC, and it will show the following:

```
 - UserA P1
 - UserA P2
 - UserB P2
 - UserB P3
 - UserC P3
 - UserC P3
 - UserA P4
 - UserB P4
```

What I would like to see, ideally, would be this (using the same data):

```
 - UserA P1
 - UserB P2
 - UserC P3
 - Rest of tickets ordered by priority
```

Is that possible to do in JQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have an option to do it in JQL but you can directly access the jira database.

You can get some more information about the database schema here

[JIRA Database schema](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-architecture/database-schema)

For example this is the description of `jiraissue` table

```
mysql> desc jiraissue;
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID                   | decimal(18,0) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| pkey                 | varchar(255)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| PROJECT              | decimal(18,0) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| REPORTER             | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ASSIGNEE             | varchar(255)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| issuetype            | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SUMMARY              | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DESCRIPTION          | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ENVIRONMENT          | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PRIORITY             | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| RESOLUTION           | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| issuestatus          | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CREATED              | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| UPDATED              | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DUEDATE              | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| RESOLUTIONDATE       | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| VOTES                | decimal(18,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| WATCHES              | decimal(18,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TIMEORIGINALESTIMATE | decimal(18,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TIMEESTIMATE         | decimal(18,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TIMESPENT            | decimal(18,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| WORKFLOW_ID          | decimal(18,0) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| SECURITY             | decimal(18,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| FIXFOR               | decimal(18,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COMPONENT            | decimal(18,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

To achieve ranking you can use the following query in MySQL

```
SELECT ASSIGNEE,
       PRIORITY,
       MAX(rank)
FROM (SELECT  ASSIGNEE,
              PRIORITY, 
              CASE 
                WHEN @prevRank = SUBSTR(PRIORITY, 2) THEN @curRank 
                WHEN @prevRank := SUBSTR(PRIORITY, 2) THEN @curRank := @curRank + 1
              END AS rank
      FROM jiraissue, 
      (SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL) r
      ORDER BY PRIORITY) t
GROUP BY ASSIGNEE
```

Refer to this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4781/23)

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping to do it in JQL, but this will also work- thank you for going the extra mile!

Comment: @VladimirMarenus you can add this filter to your board filter configuration in JIRA _project = name_of_project and assignee = name_of_user_

Answer (score 0):

It is not good to access Jira's Database. If you are looking for a query t show task for specific user you can do this:

project = name_of_project and assignee = name_of_user